# How to redirect outdated browsers with NGinx map?

Tags: browser, nginx, proxy

We have an NginX balancing proxy in front of our web application.
Unfortunately there is not enough development resources to support outdated browsers, yet :(
We want to redirect members of our web project to **/outdated** page by their browser user-agent data like this (https://www.in2circle.com/outdated).
For some reason we don't want to load back-end with User-Agent content analysis logic.
I've heard it's easy to do with NginX http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html
If somebody did so, can you help me with examples and explanations, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe someone will find this helpful.
Next solution works pretty good and is exactly what I wanted:

```
map $http_user_agent $outdated {
    default                                 0;
    "~MSIE [1-9]\."                         1;
    "~Mozilla.*Firefox/[1-9]\."             1;
    "~Mozilla.*Firefox/[0-2][0-9]\."        1;
    "~Mozilla.*Firefox/3[0-1]\."            1;
    "~Opera.*Version/[0-9]\."               1;
    "~Opera.*Version/[0-1][0-9]\."          1;
    "~Opera.*Version/2[0-1]\."              1;
    "~AppleWebKit.*Version/[0-6]\..*Safari" 1;
    "~Chrome/[0-9]\."                       1;
    "~Chrome/[0-2][0-9]\."                  1;
    "~Chrome/3[0-3]\."                      1;
}

if ($outdated = 1){
    rewrite ^ /outdated redirect;
}
```